# Compression servlet filter that supports minimum object size

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

I wish to add compression to our spring based web-service (serving both xml and json), I see that there are a number of different gzip compression filters, but not sure **which is accepted as the most common** i.e. is there a Jboss or Spring offering?

Additionally I have read that compressing content below [1000-860 bytes is pointless as compression time is greater than time saved and if its below 150 bytes that object actually grows](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31750/what-is-recommended-minimum-object-size-for-gzip-performance-benefits).

Do these filters support minimum object size out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but compression in a filter happens before the JSP is rendered. You could possibly enable it through apache, but doing it as a filter using Servlets/Filters or Spring MVC probably isn't going to help you:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?45604-Using-gzip-for-compression-how

I notice reading your question that you are using xml and json responses. You could possibly still gain some benefit from it at the Spring MVC/Controller level if that is all you are looking for, but I would probably still pursue the GZIP capabilities in Apache.

http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ehcache-web, so the http response (with headers) is cached (with gzip compression) and returned to the client. Thus, the gzip process (and the serialization) occurs only when the content is returned by spring mvc endpoints.

But ehcache-web is designed to cache pages, so you have to override the filter (SimplePageCachingFilter) to handle eviction when request verb is PUT or POST or DELETE.

You can also write your own filter, and use ehcache as a cache manager to put / evict values. The values will be structures that contains 
* the result of your endpoint invocation, serialized in json or xml (as string)
* a map for the http headers.

Unfortunately cache support in Spring mvc (@Cacheable) caches the result of method invocation, which is then serialized for each http request. It's understandable since Spring cache is agnostic and not tight to http.